# htaccess-protect a specific domain with password

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have 3 domains:

```
example.com
sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com
```

all pointing to one server and one folder.
i want to protect `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`from accessing the root folder with password, but **not** the main domain,it should be able to access root without password.
i mean :

```
example.com      => allowed
sub1.example.com => blocked with password
sub2.example.com => blocked with password
sub1.example.com/* => allowed
sub2.example.com/* => allowed
```

* is a folder that can be anything.
i tried to find it on the internet and here but i couldnt find any,how can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Password protect staging server
# Use one .htaccess file across multiple environments
# (e.g. local, dev, staging, production)
# but only password protect a specific environment.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

SetEnvIf Host staging.domain.com passreq
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any
```

Comment: what is that `staging.domain.com`

Comment: your code works but i want just root folder . `sub1.example.com/folder`should not be protected?

Comment: try adding
in subfolder 
**Order allow,deny
Allow from all**